# Footer Message Drupal

Tags: css, drupal, themes, bootstrap-4, precision

How do I adjust the footer message in Drupal? Do I need to login to Drupal dashboard or what?

I have searched almost every file in cPanel, but I could not find any of the website's actual HTML.

[I can only customize body content but not footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNQpw.jpg)

Thanks.

PS: I think they might using Drupal 7 - precision themes

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends pretty heavily on the manner in which the theme has been built. However, there are a few generic things to try. And yes you will most likely need to be logged into your site.

In a default setup, the footer content is simply a block or blocks placed in the footer region of the theme. In this case, navigate to **{site_address}/admin/structure/block** (*Structure >> Blocks* from the Admin Toolbar) and edit the blocks placed in the footer region.

If there are no blocks in that region, it is likely that the footer content is hard-coded in the theme files or configured in the theme settings. I would check:

- the files inside of the **/sites/all/themes/** directory in your
  webroot for a hard-coded footer
- the settings for your default theme configured at
  **{site_address}/admin/appearance/settings/{default_theme_name}** (*Appearance* from the
  Admin Toolbar and then *Settings* underneath your default theme) for a configuration based footer

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how it's added:

- May be hard-coded somewhere in theme files. In that case you'll have to edit theme files, /sites/all/themes/your-theme-name
- Theme may have some options/property for this - check theme prefs (under appearance)
- It may be added as a block - go to Structure -> Blocks and see if there is some block which name associates on "Drupal", "Copyright" or similar and remove it from it's block.